# Loop or sort for layered draw?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, loops

Assuming a collection of objects, each of which needs to be drawn at a specific layer, at what point would it (or ever) be better to sort each object by layer rather than looping multiple times and drawing a layer at each pass?  More importantly how would you arrive at this conclusion?  Bonus points for a sort algorithm you would use if you would sort?

```
for (obj = each in collection) {
  for (i=0; i<=topLayer; i++) {
    if (obj.layer == i) {
      obj.draw()
    }
  }
}

/* vs. */

function layerCompare(obj1, obj2) {
  return (obj1.layer > obj2.layer)
}

collection.sort(layerCompare) 

for (obj = each in collection) {
    obj.draw()
}
```

Comment: A lot of good answers here.  They are all correct in their own way so picking one is hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you loop through every layer and every object, that is O(m*n) where m is number of layers and n is number of objects. However, if you sort the layers ahead of time with something like quicksort, you can sort them in `O(n*log(n))` and then draw them in `O(n)`, yielding a total complexity of `O(n*log(n) + n) = O(n*log(n))`.

So in theory, its always better to sort them. In practice, you would have to benchmark.

EDIT: On second inspection, the cutoff is whether `m < log(n)`. If the number of layers is less than the log of the number of objects, then you should do the double loop, otherwise sort them.

Comment: Thanks for the big O break down.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  In most cases the objects will heavily outnumber the layers which is why I was considering the double loop.

Comment: You can't just divide big-O and ignore constant factors.

Comment: well, you can talk about constant factors (and that can be very important), but as far as big-O goes, you can divide out constants. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: You divide out the constants to get the big-O growth. What your m < log (n) statement is saying is absolute time, not growth, so you have divided two different constants out from each sides. You've gone from a < Ka*m*n and b < Kb*n*log(n) to having a < b implied by m < log(n), rather than a < b implied by Ka * m < Kb * log(n). The big O growth limits say nothing about whether one or the other is faster in absolute terms.

Comment: I am not assuming m (number of layers) is a constant. When I say m < log(n), m and n are both variable, but you might know for a fact that over the set of all possible m's and all possible n's m < log(n) depending on the circumstances. If you knew ahead of time how many layers where being used (or even if the number of layers is finite), then you would remove the m term.

Comment: Use a stable sort to maintain z-order for objects in the same layer.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is such that not many layers come and go, it makes vastly more sense to always keep your layers sorted.  One such way to accomplish that trivially is to make a layer itself a drawable object that can contain objects.  At this point, your layering is built into the recursive nature of the layer object itself.

Alternatively, you could just have a layer list which each layer being a single list of objects.

Answer (score 2):

I would maintain a separate collection for each layer (and not have layer as a property of each object), rendering the question moot.  Reassigning an object to a different layer (with an add and a remove) would only be (roughly) twice as expensive as changing an object's layer property, and you would completely avoid the cost of either a sort or a bunch of iterations to get the objects in each layer.

Comment: That's a good alternative and makes a lot of sense.  It would require creating new collections if the number of layers need to grow but this is likely cheaper than the double loop or the sort.

Comment: What language is this? Collections are pretty cheap in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

The big question is how smart your sort can be.  How often do items get added/removed/change layers?  Insertion and Bubble sort (generally considered poor performers) work very well for almost sorted data.

The other question is how much work do you save by sorting?  Your rendering function is great for a small number of layers, but gets worse the more layers you have.  From a complexity standpoint, you need to consider both the number of layers and the number of items, and possibly the distribution per layer.

If you have a small (small being relative of course) number of layers it might just make sense to have a separate collection (linked list probably) for each layer, and move it to the appropriate layer when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of layers is fixed, you can use [Pigeonhole sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort) which is an O(n) algorithm.  For example, if there are 256 layers numbered 0 through 255, create an array `List<Obj>[] a` of size 256, then for each object `obj` in your collection, perform `a[obj.layer].add(obj)`.  Finally, iterate through your array back to front and draw your objects (if 0 is back, `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {for (Obj obj : a[i]) {draw(obj);}}`

But I agree that maintaining these lists is better than regenerating them all the time.  The simplest approach is to store your objects in a set data structure ordered by layer that allows in-order iteration (for example, a TreeSet in Java).

Answer (score 1):

If you have *N* objects and *L* layers, the cost of the loop is *N* times the cost of drawing *C<sub>draw</sub>*, and *N × L* the cost of testing the layer *C<sub>draw</sub>*.

*C<sub>test and paint</sub> = ( C<sub>draw</sub> + C<sub>test</sub> × L ) × N*

The cost of adding an item is the insertion cost of the collection; the cost of moving objects between layers is negligible.

In most cases, the cost of drawing will be much larger than the cost of testing, ( *C<sub>draw</sub> >> C<sub>test</sub>* ) so it depends on the number of layers whether or not the *L × N* term will have a noticeable effect ( *C<sub>draw</sub> ÷ C<sub>test</sub>* >? L  ).

Sorting will mean you have about two tests and an insertion for *N ln<sub>2</sub> N*; a first approximation, this will cost about  *3 × C<sub>test</sub> N ln<sub>2</sub> N* . You shouldn't need to re-sort except when an object is added or removed or its layer changed, so the cost of drawing will generally only have the linear cost. ( the reason for using estimates of the cost rather than trying to divide different *O* values is that it gives a comparison of scale rather than growth - the cut off between *O(L N)* and *O(N ln N)* isn't when *L == ln N*, as either *O* could have a large constant term; you'd have to measure it yourself for real values rather than the guesses I've made )

*C<sub>sort and repaint</sub> = ( C<sub>draw</sub> + 3 × C<sub>test</sub> × ln<sub>2</sub> N ) × N*

*C<sub>paint only</sub> = C<sub>draw</sub> × N*

However, from a software design view I've always tended to have each layer have their own collection of members when doing editors - it makes operations on the layers better encapsulated ( show layer, hide layer, select only from one layer, move layer to top etc. ).

For reasonably complex graphics unless the number of possible layers is large, any of the approaches will be about as fast as each other, as the cost of the drawing will be the largest term. If it takes *1024 × C<sub>test</sub>* to draw a *32×32* pixel object, then you'd need more than 100 layers for  *C<sub>test and paint</sub>* to be 10% slower than  *C<sub>paint only</sub>* . Measure the times for yourself.